# Water station reports 2 different statuses, which is it?

Tags: simcity-2013

Water station reports 2 different statuses, which is it?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple pumps within that facility and its likely one of those that has gone dry, not the entire system. I constantly get a warning about one pump that has gone dry while the other three still have water below them. You can turn on the water saturation map to see the water levels easier to try and figure out which pumps are no longer over water and turn them off. You do not have to turn off the whole station, you can turn off each separate pump.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's unfortunate that the UI isn't a little clearer. On top of that, it gives me an alert (orange icon) but really there's nothing pressing. Although, I suppose that's why it's orange not and not red.

Comment: I have the same issue with one of my water pumping stations actually. It constantly tells me that its running dry just because the main part of the station is dry.. The other three pumps are running beautifully.. I just chalked it up to an annoying bug in the game as no one is going thirsty in my city.